# Finding all integers in an array with odd occurrence

Tags: java, array, complexity, hash-map

I am doing an interview exercise problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451184/java-hashsetinteger-to-int-array).

The problem is to find "all numbers that occurred an odd-number of times in an array".

Here is my high level psuedo code thinking:

1. Construct a map that will map integers to their frequencies.
2. Iterate through the array, use the map to record the frequency count.
3. Iterate through all the keys in the map and add the keys that have an odd value to another collection.
4. Convert that collection to an array and return it to the user.

Here is the my implementation of this high level psuedo code in Java:

```
public static int[] allOdd(int[] array) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int c=0;c<array.length;c++) {
        if(hm.containsKey(array[c])) {
            hm.put(array[c], hm.get(array[c]) + 1);
        } else {
            hm.put(array[c], 1);
        }
    }
    List<Integer> allOdds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int key: hm.keySet()) {
        if(hm.get(key) % 2 == 1) {
            allOdds.add(key);
        }
    }
    int[] allOs = new int[allOdds.size()];
    for(int c=0;c<allOdds.size();c ++){
        allOs[c] = allOdds.get(c);
    }
    return allOs;
}
```

I tested this for two of my test cases and in both test cases ( {2,3,2,4,4,4,6,8,8} and {90,91,91,93,93,93,95,98,98,97} ), this function produced the right results([3, 4, 6] and [97, 93, 95, 90] respectively).

Is there anything I can do to improve the time and space complexity of this method. One of the worries I had was that I created too many collections (too much space) But to me each collection had its own purpose. The map was to map values to frequencies. The `ArrayList` was a dynamic structure to hold the odd occurrences. You needed to initialize the last array because `ArrayList` is a collection that holds objects so you need to manually iterate through the `ArrayList` and store those `int`s (Auto box) in the new array. [To Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451184/java-hashsetinteger-to-int-array)

Is there anything you can point out that can improve time and space efficiency in this function?

Comment: You don't need to count the frequency. One bit would be sufficient. `0` even, `1` odd and flipping that bit for each occurence.

Comment: Take a look at [_Find elements occurring even number of times in an integer array_](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36842/9357).

Comment: @200_success in your solution, why did you need 2 sets? Why not just have 1 and then remove back and forth? Like if you have 1 1 1. It be a sequence of add 1 remove 1 add 1 and you end up with what you want.

Comment: The even-occurrences problem is harder than the odd-occurrences problem.

Comment: @200_success So all you would need here is that one set?

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need to keep track of how many times you've seen each integer, only whether you've seen it an odd number of times. So start with your data structure (map, hash table, dictionary, whatever) being empty, which correctly reflects the state that you have seen no numbers an odd number of times. Now for each number x in the array, if x is in the map then remove it (now you've seen it an even number of times) otherwise add it.

Comment: And then you just return the keyset?

Comment: Yeah. It *always* contains exactly the integers you've seen an odd number of times.

Comment: Yeah cause the question never states you have to return an int array so why go through the trouble of "autoboxing" the set of Integers into an array of ints?

Comment: So all you would need is a set then?

Comment: Yeah, you could use a set or any other data structure that supports efficient insertion, deletion and querying.

Comment: Yeah cause if its necessary to keep track of the frequency, there is no need for a map. Guess that saves some space.

Answer (score 2):

@vnp had a good point to sort the array first,
@t.niese to forego the counting and keep flipping a boolean flag instead,
and also @WilfRosenbaum to use the property of the counting data structure that elements are either in or out already mean odd or even, respectively.
In addition, @rolfl showed in an [answer to a practically duplicate question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36842/find-elements-occurring-even-number-of-times-in-an-integer-array) a technique to collect the odd numbers in-place.

Combining some of these points, and adding to them a bit, here's an alternative implementation:

```
public static int[] allOdd(int[] array) {
    if (array.length < 2) {
        return array;
    }

    int[] sorted = array.clone();
    Arrays.sort(sorted);

    boolean odd = true;
    int len = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < sorted.length; ++i) {
        if (sorted[i] == sorted[i - 1]) {
            odd = !odd;
        } else {
            if (odd) {
                sorted[len++] = sorted[i - 1];
            }
            odd = true;
        }
    }

    if (odd) {
        sorted[len++] = sorted[sorted.length - 1];
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(sorted, len);
}
```

This implementation works on a copy of the original array.
If you don't mind mutating the input parameter,
then you could save the space of the `sorted` array.

#### Unit testing

To verify that your solution works,
especially while tweaking it,
it's good to have some unit tests,
based on the given examples,
and also carefully covering corner cases too:

```
private void assertEqualSet(int[] expected, int[] actual) {
    assertEquals(arrayToSet(expected), arrayToSet(actual));
}

private Set<Integer> arrayToSet(int[] arr) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int num : arr) {
        set.add(num);
    }
    return set;
}

@Test
public void test_empty() {
    assertEqualSet(new int[0], allOdd(new int[0]));
}

@Test
public void test_1() {
    assertEqualSet(new int[]{1}, allOdd(new int[]{1}));
}

@Test
public void test_1_2() {
    assertEqualSet(new int[]{1, 2}, allOdd(new int[]{1, 2}));
}

@Test
public void test_1_1() {
    assertEqualSet(new int[0], allOdd(new int[]{1, 1}));
}

@Test
public void test_1_2_1() {
    assertEqualSet(new int[]{2}, allOdd(new int[]{1, 2, 1}));
}

@Test
public void test_2_3_2_4_4_4_6_8_8() {
    assertEqualSet(new int[]{3, 4, 6}, allOdd(new int[]{2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 8, 8}));
}

@Test
public void test_90_91_91_93_93_93_95_98_98_97() {
    assertEqualSet(new int[]{97, 93, 95, 90}, allOdd(new int[]{90, 91, 91, 93, 93, 93, 95, 98, 98, 97}));
}
```

#### Code review

A few other things can be improved about your implementation.

---

When you don't need the element indexes when iterating over an array,
use a for-each loop. So instead of:

> ```
> for(int c=0;c<array.length;c++) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

This is better:

```
for (int num : array) {
    // ...
}
```

---

This code performs a hash lookup twice: once in `containsKey`, and then in `get`:

> ```
> if (hm.containsKey(num)) {
>     hm.put(num, hm.get(num) + 1);
> } else {
>     hm.put(num, 1);
> }
> ```

You could factor out one lookup by using a `get` and a null-check.
The code is also shorter this way, with less duplicated elements:

```
Integer count = hm.get(num);
if (count == null) {
    count = 0;
}
hm.put(num, count + 1);
```

Comment: How do you know what the edge cases are?

Comment: You think hard, and ask yourself questions like: "what can possibly go wrong", "what input could break the function". Typical edge cases are small inputs, empty input, degenerate inputs (array of all the same values). Stuff like that. For the record, your implementation passes all the tests I could think of. My point was just a general tip about unit testing.

Comment: Did you put the test code as part of the class code. In my JUnit test code, I had to always call ClassName.allOdd(...)?

Comment: Yes, JUnit tests should go to their own file. For the sake of simplicity I put them in the same class in my local version. It's a minor technical detail and not really relevant for this discussion. You can easily move these tests to a separate file and add a helper method there with the name `allOdd` that simply calls `return ClassName.allOdd`.

Comment: In general software, is it up to you to decide how to return all the values with odd occurrences in an array? Like you're given an array. Do you usually have flexibility in choosing what kind of data structure to return those values back in - set, array, etc?

Comment: In general software, it should be up to you. If it's logical that the elements of the returned array should be unique, then the right type to return is a `Set`, as it contains that specific important detail. So in real life this method should return a `Set<Integer>`, not a `int[]`, and you should be able to implement it that way. Programming contests focus on algorithms and problem solving, not so much on API design and code organization.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Java expert. I just know that `map` *may* degenerate in a linear list giving a worst case performance of \$O(n^2)\$. Facing question like this I'd first (heap- or merge-) sort the array, and then scan it counting repetitions. \$O(n \log{n})\$ time is pretty much guaranteed, with no space penalty.

Comment: What do you mean by degenerate?

Comment: Technical term: decline or deteriorate; in a pathological case perform much worse than expected in average.

Comment: MathJax indeed. `\$ math \$`

Comment: Would using just one hashset resolve that issue of the worst case of O(\$n^2\$)?

Comment: I believe so. Such is a nature of a worst case - being worst.

Comment: Would HashSet work better than? Because insert in hashset is just O(1), you just put it into the bucket and then you take it out if you find a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

import java.util.HashSet;

public class OddOccurence {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,3,8,8}; 
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<String>();

    System.out.println(a[i] );
    for( i = 0 ; i<a.length; i++){
        int counter = 0;
        for( j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
            if(a[i]==a[j])
                counter++;
        }
        if(counter%2 != 0)
            result.add(Integer.toString(a[i]));     
    }

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.